# How to reduce multiple if statements complexity

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, foreach

I feel like the 5 if statements can be done with one line of code or fewer lines. I was thinking of using the `forEach` method but I can not wrap my mind around improving this correctly.

```
var previous_stays = 12,
    booking_agency_id = null,
    reservation_spend = 375.95,
    room_spend = [12.23,2.35,null,17.99],
    reservation_nights = 4,
    gold_tier = 0;

while (gold_tier == 0) {
 a = (previous_stays >= 5);
 b = !booking_agency_id;
 c = reservation_spend;
 d = reservation_nights;

 if (room_spend.length > 0) {
     c = c + room_spend[0];
     if (room_spend.length > 1) {
         c = c + room_spend[1];
         if (room_spend.length > 2) {
             c = c + room_spend[2];
             if (room_spend.length > 3) {
                 c = c + room_spend[3];
                 if (room_spend.length > 4) {
                     c = c + room_spend[4];
                     if (room_spend.length > 5) {
                         c = c + room_spend[5];
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }

 if (!(((c/d) > 250) && a && b)) {
   break;
 }

 gold_tier = 1;
}
```

Comment: `c = room_spend[room_spend.length]`

Comment: it looks like you're just adding the sum of `room_spend` to `c` so it's just: `c = room_spend.reduce((a, e) => a + e, reservation_spend)`

Comment: What's the point of `while` loop here? It only runs once.

Comment: It will be to your benefit to **explain** what this is supposed to do

Comment: @marzelin that works! But what exactly is the .reduce actually doing?

Comment: `reduce` is a tool for transforming an array into something else, in this case it adds all of the elements and returns the sum. You can learn more about reduce here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the issue is "what is 0, 1, 2, 3..." that you are comparing with? Let's say you receive it as a parameter called "category". So All operations could be reduced to:

```
if(room_spend.length > category){
     c = c + room_spend[category]
}
```

So the issue is to give some meaning to this "category".

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, set the max length that you want to check for and loop backwards.

```
let l = 6; // (max length +1)
while(l-->0) if (room.spend.length>l) { c = c+room_spend[l]; break;}
```

```js
let room={spend:"1234"}

let l = 6
while(l-->0) if (room.spend.length>l) { console.log('c = c + room_spend['+l+']'); break;}
```